# Signing In and Scraping Webpages with Scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

Hoping some one is able to help me with this. I am using Scrapy to login and scrape data. This particular code works for one website. But I have another website that Scrapy cannot log on to because of the following issue:
There are no form elements on the page.

The username and password fields, and the submit button are not in a form element, instead they are in a table element, which makes it a bit confusing. How can I make Scrapy log into the webpage using the table/tr elements....and not the form element?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):

  name = 'project'

  allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]

  start_urls = ["theloginURL"]

  #this function will look for the form element and login with the username and password

  def parse(self, response):

  return [FormRequest.from_response(response,

  formdata={'user_name': ' username123', 'Password': ' psd123'},

  formxpath='//*[@name="Form1"]',callback=self.after_login)]
```

This is the HTML code that is on the log in page, in case you guys need it:

```
<table height="260px" id="loginMainTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody><tr>
    <td>
        <table align="center" class="blueBorder" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">   

<tbody><tr class="HeaderFooterHide">
<td id="companyTD" width="100%" colspan="3" style="position:relative;">
<span class="header1 header1pos">       
    Application and Network Access Portal       
</span>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td width="32px">                           
                <img src="/uniquesig6d7a33b352f4c09846f8a6563bae192b/uniquesig0/InternalSite/images/headertopl.gif" align="absmiddle">
            </td>
            <td style="background-image: url('/uniquesig6d7a33b352f4c09846f8a6563bae192b/uniquesig0/InternalSite/images/headertopm.gif'); background-repeat: repeat-x">             
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td width="520px" style="background-image: url('/uniquesig6d7a33b352f4c09846f8a6563bae192b/uniquesig0/InternalSite/images/headertopr.gif');">                               
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody></table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="HeaderFooterHide">
<td width="100%" colspan="3" style="position:relative;">    
<span style="position:absolute;margin-left:20px;">      

</span>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td width="30px">                           
                <img src="/uniquesig6d7a33b352f4c09846f8a6563bae192b/uniquesig0/InternalSite/images/headerbottoml.gif" align="absmiddle">
            </td>
            <td style="background-image: url('/uniquesig6d7a33b352f4c09846f8a6563bae192b/uniquesig0/InternalSite/images/headerbottomm.gif'); background-repeat: repeat-x">              
            &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td width="30px" style="background-image: url('/uniquesig6d7a33b352f4c09846f8a6563bae192b/uniquesig0/InternalSite/images/headerbottomr.gif');">                             
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>    
    </td>
 </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="contentleft">                                
                </td>
                <td align="center" class="internalTD">
                    <table width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                        <form id="form1" name="form1" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="/uniquesig6d7a33b352f4c09846f8a6563bae192b/uniquesig0/InternalSite/Validate.asp" onsubmit="return(SubmitForm());"></form>
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td valign="top" height="250px" align="center">
                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="content">

                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td class="msgText">Log On</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="content">

                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <td class="paramText">Username</td>
                                            <td><input class="paramTextbox" type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" maxlength="50" size="11"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="paramText">Password</td>
                                            <td><input class="paramTextbox" type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="20" onkeypress="capsDetect(arguments[0]);" size="11"></td>                                             
                                        </tr>

                                                <input type="hidden" id="repository" name="repository" value="ADLDS" size="11">

                                    <tr height="0px">
                                        <td colspan="2" id="capsLockTD" height="0px">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td class="EzBiz_Text1"><input name="chkUsername" type="CHECKBOX" onclick="saveUserName()" id="chkUsername">Remember my User ID</td>
                                    </tr>   
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2" align="right">
                                            <input border="0" class="button" type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Log On">
                                        </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                                <div class="EzBiz_Loginbutton" style="float: left;">
                                    <input border="0" class="EzBiz_Button" type="image" id="submit_button" src="/uniquesig6d7a33b352f4c09846f8a6563bae192b/uniquesig0/InternalSite/images/CustomUpdate/login_submit.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div class="EzBiz_PasswordForget">
                                    <img src="/uniquesig6d7a33b352f4c09846f8a6563bae192b/uniquesig0/InternalSite/images/CustomUpdate/arrow.gif">
                                    <a href="hhttps:www.url.vom" target="_blank">Did you forget your password?</a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <input type="hidden" name="site_name" id="site_name" value="ezbizportal">
                        <input type="hidden" name="secure" id="secure" value="1">
                        <input type="hidden" name="resource_id" id="resource_id" value="49203789E2E14C4A92CEC904C24909CE">
                        <input type="hidden" name="login_type" id="login_type" value="2">

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="content" width="100%">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td id="openerExistsTD" class="notification">
                                        For security purposes, when you finish working with this site do one of the following:<li>Click the Logoff button to log off from the site.</li><li>Close all browser windows (including applications that are open in other windows).</li>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>       
                                    <!-- Windows XP Service Pack 2  / 2003 / Vista Message - Start -->

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="notification">
                                        This site is intended for authorized users only.<br>
                                        If you experience access problems contact the <a href="mailto:">site administrator</a>.
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                            </td>    
                        </tr>


                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
                <td class="contentright">                       
                </td>
            </tr>

<tr class="HeaderFooterHide">
<td width="100%" colspan="3" style="position:relative;">
<span class="bottomText bottomTextPos">     
    © 2010 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. <a href="javascript:alert('Microsoft Corporation licenses the software and services on this portal to you according to your Microsoft Unified Access Gateway 2010 (the &quot;software&quot;) license. You may not use this portal without a license for the software. Contact your IT administrator for the license terms.')">Terms and Conditions.</a>
    </span>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td width="47px">                           
                <img src="/uniquesig6d7a33b352f4c09846f8a6563bae192b/uniquesig0/InternalSite/images/footerbgl.gif" align="absmiddle">
            </td>
            <td style="background-image: url('/uniquesig6d7a33b352f4c09846f8a6563bae192b/uniquesig0/InternalSite/images/footerbgm.gif'); background-repeat: repeat-x">              
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td width="47px" style="background-image: url('/uniquesig6d7a33b352f4c09846f8a6563bae192b/uniquesig0/InternalSite/images/footerbgr.gif');">                             
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>            
</td>
</tr>

        </tbody></table>
    </td>
</tr>   
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: The formatting of the code in your post appears to have some issues, and it looks like you are defining the class twice. Can you correct the code issues (perhaps by creating a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I accidentally pasted the class twice, I went ahead and pasted all the code, excluding the website. I also pasted part of the HTML code for the login page. Notice, how the input elements are not inside a form tag, the code above is looking for a form. How can I fix the code to be able to log in to this HTML page?

Comment: Hi, still looking for some help!

Comment: I would try to revise your question to only include _the important information_. Right now there is a lot of code in here but not much explanation of what you are trying to do, and I suspect that much of the code is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I revised my question. However I still kept the HTML code just in case you needed. I would imagine that the code you really need to focus on is the the python code, which I only included the important functions.

Comment: I imagine that the HTML code is needed to see what elements to use with Scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

A generic login module would be more useful. Try [scrapy loginform library](https://github.com/scrapy/loginform):

### Install

```
pip install -i https://pypi.binstar.org/pypi/simple loginform
```

### Code

```
from loginform import fill_login_form
import requests
url = "https://example.com/login"
r = requests.get(url)
result=fill_login_form(url, text, 'username', 'password')
```

### About

> loginform is a library for filling HTML login forms given the login
>   url, username & password. Which form and fields to fill are inferred
>   automatically.